# How hibernate decide which of FetchMode use by default?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

In our project we use Hibernate, and in logs we observe that it sometimes use Join and sometimes Select for relations (as I understand it's FetchMode) when we didnt specify FetchMode.

How do Hibernate decide which one of FetchMode use if no specified?

Is there any specification for this? Any lines of code? Any Article?

Comment: http://www.solidsyntax.be/2013/10/17/fetching-collections-hibernate/

Comment: There is "when" (Lazy, Eager) and there is "how" (Select, Join, etc.) in relation to FetchMode. It seems you are interested in "how"". Try reading the official [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html), there are some details about default mode.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the Hibernate annotation @Fetch is not present on a field, then the default FetchMode for this field is:

- if this field has FetchType = EAGER, then FetchMode = JOIN.
- Otherwise, FetchMode = SELECT.

My source for this information is the code itself (Hibernate 5.0): [HERE](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationBinder.java#L2999), [HERE](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/CollectionBinder.java#L682) and most importantly, [HERE](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationBinder.java#L3259).

Comment: `FetchMode` depends also on how a query is done (`Session.get`, Criteria API, JPQL). See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61430192/7873775

Answer (score 2):

If a field is not annotated with `@Fetch`, then the default `FetchMode` for this field depends on a `FetchType` and how the query is done:

- `FetchType.LAZY` => `FetchMode.SELECT`
- `FetchType.EAGER`:

  - getting by ID (`Session.get`) => `FetchMode.JOIN`
  - JPQL query => `FetchMode.SELECT`
  - Criteria API query => `FetchMode.SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

Looking the generated SQL when no `FetchMode` is specified and the FetchType is `EAGER`, the default is `JOIN` in Hibernate.

Sadly, I can't find this information in the official docs.

About the use of `SELECT` even when `JOIN` is default, I supposed that are some queries that can't be resolved in a one single query, [like this](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SomeExplanationsOnLazyLoadingone-to-one):

> But if you allow B without C, Hibernate just HAS TO check presence of
>   C at the moment it loads B. But a SELECT to check presence is just
>   inefficient because the same SELECT may not just check presence, but
>   load entire object. So lazy loading goes away.